# Implementing recursion in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently working on recursion in Python but even though my process is correct I do not get my output format as I wanted.

```
def fibonacci(n):
if n <= 2:
    return 1
else:
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

def fibseries(N):
    if N <= 1:
        return []
    return [fibseries(N-1),fibonacci(N-1)]
a = fibseries(5)
print a
```

This gives me the output :

```
[[[[[0], 1], 1], 2], 3]
```

but I want to get:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

I need to understand the thinking process.

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python?rq=1 possible duplicate

Comment: It looks like you are returning an array each tim, hence the nesting

Comment: Check out http://pythontutor.com

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `fibseries` returns a list and within `fibseries` you do:

```
return [fibseries(N-1),fibonacci(N-1)]
```

you should concatenate the `fibonacci` output:

```
return fibseries(N-1) + [fibonacci(N-1)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much now I understand my mistake and I can get my result in the given format!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line `return [fibseries(N-1),fibonacci(N-1)]`. Each time you call fibseries, it returns a list so this line creates a new list with two elements, the first of which is itself a list. To get it to do what you want replace that line with `return [*fibseries(N-1),fibonacci(N-1)]`. The star will expand the first list and add the elements separately.c